# How to give ownership of created review to another user during creation

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a user review website.  I need to give ownership of a created review to another user.  Here is my code

_form,html.erb file

```html
<%= form_with(model: review, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if review.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(review.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this review from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% review.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field-group">
    <%= form.label :Review_Title %>
    <%= form.select(:title, options_for_select([ ['Excellent Experience','Excellent Experience'], ['Great Experience','Great Experience'], ['Average Experience','Average Experience'], ['Poor Experience','Poor Experience'], ['Terrible Experience','Terrible Experience']])) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field-group">
    <%= form.label :rating %>
    <%= form.number_field :rating, min: 1, max:5, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field-group">
    <%= form.label :"Description"%>
    <%= form.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field-group">
    <%= form.label :reviewer %>
    <%= form.text_field :reviewer, class: "form-control", value:current_user.name, :disabled => true %>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="field-group">
    <%= form.label :"User Reviewing" %>
    <%= form.select :user_reviewed, User. where("email <> ?", current_user.email).pluck(:email, :name), :prompt => "Select one", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  
  <br>

  <div class="actions-group">
    <%= form.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The create file from the reviews controller

```
def create
@review = current_user.reviews.new(review_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @review.save
    format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @review }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

This code gives ownership of the file to the current_user and I am trying to get the information of a different.  The email of the user that I want is passed in the form and saved in user_reviewed.  Is there a way to replace the current_user code before the reviews.new(review_params)?

```html
# Table name: reviews
#
#  id            :bigint           not null, primary key
#  description   :text
#  rating        :integer
#  reviewer      :string
#  title         :string
#  user_reviewed :string
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#  user_id       :bigint
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_reviews_on_user_id  (user_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (user_id => users.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to replace the `current_user` code before the `reviews.new(review_params)`

That's not the right way to look at this.

Your review seems to have two things, which are named:

1. The person who wrote the review. (`reviewer` is their name)
2. The person who "owns" the review. (`user_reviewed` is their email, and `user_id` is their ID.)

This is super confusing. (And I'm really not clear what the *thing being reviewed* actually is???!! Reviews have a `title` and a `description`, but is it supposed to be linked to something??) Is this supposed to be about one user reviewing another user? I don't understand.

It seems to me that you should actually be persisting two IDs, and neither  user's email address/name, in this table. So instead, it could be named:

- `author_id` -- The user who wrote the review
- `owner_id` -- The user who owns the review

And in the view, instead of doing this:

```
<%= form.select :user_reviewed, User.where("email <> ?", current_user.email).pluck(:email, :name), :prompt => "Select one", class: "form-control" %>
```

You can do something like this:

```
<%= form.select :owner_id, User.where("id <> ?", current_user.id).pluck(:id, :name), :prompt => "Select one", class: "form-control" %>
```

Then in the `User` model, you can draw a clear distinction between:

```
user.reviews_written # joins on the author_id
user.reviews_owned # joins on the owner_id
```

And in the controller, you should make use of `current_user` for what it actually means:

```
@review = current_user.reviews_written.new(review_params)
```

Comment: The is for a Auction website and people are reviewing other people like how they do on amazon or ebay.  After working on this for the pass few days I do agree that it is super confusing, but its a group project so I can't change the names that easily

Comment: Is there anyway to get the User?

Comment: *"its a group project so I can't change the names that easily"* -- Sorry, but that's not a good excuse. I've worked for several years, in multiple companies/projects, sometimes alongside dozens of other developers. I rename things all the time. There's no use working on code that you're unable to change. If things are poorly named, then rename them.

Comment: If a reviewer is between two users, then name it sensibly. How about: `reviewer_id` and `reviewed_user_id`? Again, there's no need to duplicate data like `name` or `email` across both tables -- you should be able to access it like: `review.reviewer.name`, or `review.reviewed_user.email`.

Comment: *"Is there anyway to get the User?"* -- I'm not sure I understand the question. `User.find_by!(email: ....)`?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out.  I was just overthinking the issue.